# Stomp listeners are dropping after some time but program is running without showing any errors

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp, stomp.py

I have a stomp listener on an Activemq queue which just drops itself after being up for a while.
The program itself shows no error and shows in running state but listener listed on Activemq UI just shows 0 after some time.
I am using this code

```
class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.msg = []

    def on_error(self, frame):
        print('received an error "%s"' % frame.body)

    def on_message(self, frame):
        print('received a message "%s" from queue' % frame.body)
        headers = frame.headers
        self.conn.ack(id=headers["message-id"], subscription=headers["subscription"])

    def on_disconnected(self):
        print('disconnected')
        connect_and_subscribe(self.conn)
def main():
    conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 61613)])
    a = MyListener(conn)
    conn.set_listener('', a)
    connect_and_subscribe(conn)
    try:
        while True:
            if not conn.is_connected():
               print('disconnected... connecting again')
               connect_and_subscribe(conn)
            time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('interrupted - so exiting!')
    conn.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't using STOMP [heart-beating](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating) it's not terribly surprising that your application would not detect the dead connection.

You can configure heart-beating like so:

```
conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 61613)], heartbeats=(4000, 4000))
```

See the [stomp.py documentation](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html?highlight=heartbeat#dealing-with-disconnects) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but after adding heartbeats my consumer started to connect and disconnect on a frequent basis.(per 12 seconds to be exact). I have used 4000,4000 in heartbeats.

Comment: That indicates to me that heart-beating is failing. Do you have any idea why heart-beating would fail?

Comment: AcitveMQ server is up all the time. I don't really know why would it fail. Are there any other reasons for this. Thanks.

Comment: A network delay or failure could cause this as well as a heavy load on the broker. I'm sure there are other potential causes as well, but those are the most likely off the top of my head.

Comment: @AviralTyagi Did you find out what is the problem? I am running into the same issue

Comment: If the ActiveMQ is hosted on EKS (as a pod) then this problem is still there. I had to create a middleware which can detect dropped consumers and restart the services.
If ActiveMQ is running on a server then this solution did stabilize the connections. (for longer time periods ie. days)

Comment: @AviralTyagi Sorry, I didn't get a notification on your reply. ActiveMQ is running on a server. Yes, I notice that it runs at least for 2-3 days. Can you point me to any possibility of resolving the issue? Or is restarting the app only the solution?

Comment: @Jane No, I did not find any solution for this. I had to create a middleware which can restart the app when the consumer goes down.

Comment: If your application is using heart-beats with a competent STOMP client then it should detect any connection failure and allow the application to respond appropriately (e.g. stop, reconnect, etc.). You shouldn't have to write _another_ application to restart it.